# CompletableFuture with supplyAsync not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, future, completable-future

I am doing some experiments with the Java CompletableFuture. Here is the code

```
public class SpringBootAsyncApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() - > {

            return MailUtil.getMailInfo();

        }).thenAccept(content - > {
            System.out.println("Mail content: " + content);
        });
    }

}

class MailUtil {
    public static String getMailInfo() {
        return "Your email content";
    }

    public static boolean sendMail() {
        System.out.println("Send mail: completed");
        return true;
    }

    public static void logging() {
        System.out.println("Log: Send mail at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

I run the program 3 times. All of them didn't return any output ? But when I replace `return MailUtil.getMailInfo();` with number 5

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() - > {

    return 5;

}).thenAccept(content - > {
    System.out.println("Mail content: " + content);
});
```

then it runs as normal. Why is that ?

Comment: I've run your code and it outputs "Mail content: Your email content". Edit. I've run the code multiple times and actually it sometimes it prints the output and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Thats strange. I am running on intelliji and it doesn't output the result
Here is the link to the output : https://imgur.com/a/jTF6rzX

Comment: This is just a coincidence - the main thread exits before your async tasks are executed/completed. Add `.join()` at the end and you will always see the result.

Comment: so by default completable future executes its task on DAEMON THREAD ?

Comment: @kungho from [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-): "task running in the ForkJoinPool.commonPool()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result that you see is just a coincidence. The main thread exits before your async tasks are executed/completed. Add [`CompletableFuture::join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join()) at the end and you will always see the result :

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() - > {

    return MailUtil.getMailInfo();

}).thenAccept(content - > {
    System.out.println("Mail content: " + content);
}).join();
```

This is because when you use `supplyAsync` your task will be executed in one of the threads from `ForkJoinPool.commonPool` and by default threads from this pool are daemon threads so they do not stop JVM from exiting. You can verify this by checking the default thread factory associated with `commonPool` :

```
ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
ForkJoinWorkerThread forkJoinWorkerThread = ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory.newThread(forkJoinPool);

boolean daemon = forkJoinWorkerThread.isDaemon();
System.out.println(daemon);
```

And the output is `true`.